# Why is my angular2 method not working properly?

Tags: angular

**QUESTION:**

When the component loads, the alreadyVotedFor() method seems to not be called. Why is that ?

I added some logging to the service but nothing is logged to the console.

What I am trying to achieve is to pre-select the choice the user already made previously and prevent him from voting twice.

Open the browser console to see the errors.

---

**EDIT:**

Current issue logging (component.ts ngOninit()):

```
NGONINIT this.votes: undefined
SUBSCRIBE COMPLETE this.votes: undefined
```

---

**CODE:**

**component.html**

```
<article class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      {{ poll.title }}
      <br>
      <br>
      <form #form="ngForm">
        <fieldset [disabled]="alreadyVotedFor(-1)">
          {{ poll.counter1 }} votes <input type="radio" id="{{ poll.choice1 }}" name="my_radio" value="{{ poll.choice1 }}" (click)="onChoice1(form)" [checked]="alreadyVotedFor(1)">  {{ poll.choice1 }}
          <br>
          {{ poll.counter2 }} votes <input type="radio" id="{{ poll.choice2  }}" name="my_radio" value="{{ poll.choice2 }}" (click)="onChoice2(form)" [checked]="alreadyVotedFor(2)">  {{ poll.choice2 }}
        </fieldset>
      </form>

    </div>
    <footer class="panel-footer">
        <div class="author">
            {{ poll.username }}
        </div>
        <div class="config" *ngIf="belongsToUser()">
            <a (click)="onEdit()">Edit</a>
            <a (click)="onDelete()">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</article>
```

**component.ts**

```
votes: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.pollService.voted(this.poll, localStorage.getItem('userId')).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.votes = data.votes;
            console.log("NGONINIT this.votes: "+ this.votes);
        },
        err => { console.log("NGONINIT ERROR: "+ err) },
        () => { console.log("SUBSCRIBE COMPLETE this.votes: "+ this.votes); }
    );
}

alreadyVotedFor(choice: number) {
      let result = "";
      if (this.votes) {
          console.log("THIS.VOTES: "+this.votes);
          for (var i = 0; i < this.votes.length; i ++) {
              if (this.votes[i].poll == this.poll.pollId) {
                  result = "disabled";
                  if (this.votes[i].choice == choice) {
                      result =  "selected";
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      return result;
    }
```

**service**

```
voted(poll: Poll, userID: string) {
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/'+userID,{headers: headers})
                    .map(response => response.json());
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Do you see any mistake here ?

**service**

Here is the method that saves the user's vote:

```
voteOn(poll: Poll, userID: string, choice: number) {
      var user;
      this.http.get('https://voting-app-10.herokuapp.com/'+userID)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(
            json => {
              user = json,
              user.votes.push({poll, choice });
              const body = JSON.stringify(user);
              const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
              const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
                  ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token')
                  : '';
              return this.http.patch('https://voting-app-10.herokuapp.com/user'+token, body, {headers: headers})
                  .map((response: Response) => response.json())
                  .catch((error: Response) => {
                      this.errorService.handleError(error);
                      return Observable.throw(error);
                  })
                  .subscribe();
            }
       )
    }
```

**user.model.ts**

```
import { Poll } from '../polls/poll.model';

export class User {
    constructor(public email: string,
                public password: string,
                public votes?: [{poll: Poll, choice : number }],
                public firstName?: string,
                public lastName?: string
                ) {}
}
```

**routes/user**

```
router.get('/:userid', function (req, res, next) {
  var userId = req.params.userid;
  User.findById(userID, function (err, user) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(user);
    console.log("USER JSON? :"+body);
    return res.json(body) ;
  });
});
```

Comment: Wrong syntax on binding. Link to the doc https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax

Comment: Same basic syntax error in multiple places. Things like `selected="alreadyVotedFor(1)"` which should be `[selected]="alreadyVotedFor(1)"`. So you missed binding with `[]` in various places. i.e if it's an "expression/function" then you want `[]`

Comment: Why the downvote ? I am ready to modify the question if necessary. But please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<article class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      {{ poll.title }}
      <br>
      <br>
      <form #form="ngForm">
        <fieldset [disabled]="alreadyVotedFor(-1)">
          {{ poll.counter1 }} votes <input type="radio" id="{{ poll.choice1 }}" name="my_radio" value="{{ poll.choice1 }}" (click)="onChoice1(form)" [selected]="alreadyVotedFor(1)">  {{ poll.choice1 }}
          <br>
          {{ poll.counter2 }} votes <input type="radio" id="{{ poll.choice2  }}" name="my_radio" value="{{ poll.choice2 }}" (click)="onChoice2(form)" [selected]="alreadyVotedFor(2)">  {{ poll.choice2 }}
        </fieldset>
      </form>

    </div>
    <footer class="panel-footer">
        <div class="author">
            {{ poll.username }}
        </div>
        <div class="config" *ngIf="belongsToUser()">
            <a (click)="onEdit()">Edit</a>
            <a (click)="onDelete()">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</article>

votes: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.pollService.voted(this.poll, localStorage.getItem('userId')).subscribe(
        data => {
            this.votes = data.votes;
        },
        err => { },
        () => { }
    );
}

alreadyVotedFor(choice: number) {
    let result = "";
    if (this.votes) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.votes.length; i ++) {
            if (this.votes[i].poll == this.poll.pollId) {
                result = "disabled";
                if (this.votes[i].choice == choice) {
                    result =  "selected";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

voted(poll: Poll, userID: string) {
    return this.http.get('/'+userID)
                    .map(response => response.json());
}
```

Comment: Please go to: https://voting-app-10.herokuapp.com/polls and open the console, I don't know what's happening.

Comment: I saw the problem. You should not bind the method to each item.

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting ? I binded it in the template, where should I have binded it ?

Comment: Please change your code accordingly. If you bind the method directly to each option. It will create tons of API call.

Comment: Well, I only have 4 option for 2 polls right now. Also, I cannot do what you did with ngInit since the method signature is wrong and I cannot pass any choice there.

Comment: I do not understand what you do mean by 'signature is wrong'. Your component needs to implement OnInit and import the interface from @angular/core.

Comment: voted is a method which requires 3 arguments, the third one being choice. In this case, there is no way to pass choice.

Comment: Oops, you also modified the method. My bad. Let me recheck.

Comment: Ok, I tried your method, it does not work: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: Now, there a 0 errors in the console, but I can vote as many times as I want and nothing is preselected ... Hmmm

Comment: this.votes[i].poll is undefined. I copied it from your code. Does vote really have poll property in it?

Comment: Yes, just added user model to question.

Comment: Do you want me to send you the zip with the project code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144734/discussion-between-wannadream-and-coder1000).

Answer (score 1):

You should box the disabled attribute so that Angular will bind to it.

```
<fieldset disabled="alreadyVotedFor(-1)">
```

should be:

```
<fieldset [disabled]="alreadyVotedFor(-1)">
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue depends on this line:

```
<fieldset [disabled]="alreadyVotedFor(-1)">
```

And this function:

```
voted(poll: Poll, userID: string, choice: number) {
      var user;
      this.http.get('/'+userID)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(json => user = json)
        var result = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < user.votes.length; i ++) {
          if (user.votes[i].poll == poll.pollId) {
            result = "disabled";
            if (user.votes[i].choice == choice) {
              result =  "selected";
            }
          }
        }
        console.log("RESULT:"+result);
        return result;
    }
```

This function is linked to an attribute of the HTML with a two way data binding. It means that it executes always your code to evaluate your expression.
Considering that your code has an AJAX request, it starts infinite AJAX requests. 
You should change your code in order to trigger the AJAX request not always but only the first time? only after a value in the form changes? I don't know your use case but you can't start HTTP requests directly in this way, otherwise they will start always 
Moreover from the error it seems that you have a type inside your JSON answer which makes it impossible to parse from the browser.

Although the best solution is to perform this operation on init of the controller, considering your code the fastest change you can do is to store the retrieved value inside an attribute of the service, and avoid to perform another request if one already started. 
So the code can be something like this.

Add an attribute to the service as `result = undefined;` instead of keeping it local. 
Then inside your current `voted function change it in this way:`

```
voted(poll: Poll, userID: string, choice: number) {
      if (!this.result) {
         var user;
      this.http.get('/'+userID)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe(json => user = json)
        for (var i = 0; i < user.votes.length; i ++) {
          if (user.votes[i].poll == poll.pollId) {
            this.result = "disabled";
            if (user.votes[i].choice == choice) {
              this.result =  "selected";
            }
          }
        }
        console.log("RESULT:"+ this.result);
      }
      return this.result;
    }
```

Comment: I know. My question is how should I modify the binding and the function :/

Comment: when do you want to retrieve this value? just once at the beginning?

Comment: Exactly :D That's what I am trying to do.

Comment: The easiest way considering your code is just to store the value once returned, and not make the request again. **BUT** I strongly recommend you to move this code to the init of the controller and perform your request there. Changing the code above

Comment: I agree with you and this was what wannadream was suggesting but his implementation of the method voted is wrong since there is no choice parameter in it.

Comment: Looked at your answer, user will still be undefined, no ?

Comment: user will be defined only the first time when you still don't have a result. After you performed your first request, you will have user and result defined and no more requests should start through that method. 
If you want a refactor of this code, maybe you should think to setup a complete jsfiddle with it, so users can test and change it

Comment: jsfiddle would be impossible due to the complexity of the app, but I can share a zip.

Comment: yep share me the zip, moving the discussion to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144725/discussion-between-quirimmo-and-coder1000).